# Android - A button with Image + background + text

Tags: android, button, imagebutton

I have a button, the button has a background and a src Image icon.
Now I want to have a text on the bottom, inside my button.

**How can I achieve this?**

I cannot use ImageButton as it doesn't handle text.
Also I cannot use Button as it doesn't handle src Image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

Use `android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"`

```
       <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="Button" />
```

Or

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/btn_lay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Cal" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

**ClickListener**

```
 RelativeLayout btn_lay = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.btn_lay);

 btn_lay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                        // Do Something
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but...
That will put the drawable Image on the Top side of my button, but I want it centered and I prefer not to use padding because I want to be exact on multiple devices. any other idea?

Comment: @Campiador in button there is no options for that.

Comment: @Campiador If you need exactly like that try my edit .

Comment: @Campiador yes you can. write `onClickListener` for `btn_lay RelativeLayout` like my edit.

Comment: Set the bottom padding at runtime to be the height of the drawableTop